# Deletion of compressed file after extracting it with nunrar

Tags: c#, .net, io, delete-file

I used the lib `Nunrar` [site](http://nuget.org/packages/nunrar) to extract  a `.rar` file:

```
RarArchive.WriteToDirectory(fs.Name, Path.Combine(@"D:\DataDownloadCenter", path2), ExtractOptions.Overwrite);
```

the decompression works fine, but I can't after this operation of extract delete the original compressed file

```
System.IO.File.Delete(path);
```

because the file is *is used by another process*
the hole function :

```
 try
           {
               FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path);
               if(path.Contains(".rar")){

                   try
                   {
                       RarArchive.WriteToDirectory(fs.Name, Path.Combine(@"D:\DataDownloadCenter", path2), ExtractOptions.Overwrite);
                       fs.Close();

                   }
                   catch { }

                   }

           catch { return; }
           finally
           {
               if (zf != null)
               {
                   zf.IsStreamOwner = true; // Makes close also shut the underlying stream
                   zf.Close(); // Ensure we release resources
               }
           }
           try
           {
               System.IO.File.Delete(path);
           }
           catch { }
```

So can I delete the compressed file after extract it?

Comment: What's the type of `fs` (where you're using `fs.Name`)? I'm not familiar with the library but it seems you might've opened a `FileStream` and not closed it.

Comment: it is a `FileStream` and i did `fs.Close() ` before the delete operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `zf` is but you can also likely wrap that in a `using` statement. Try replacing your `FileStream fs` part with this

```
using( FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    if(path.Contains(".rar"))
    {
        try
        {
           RarArchive.WriteToDirectory(fs.Name, Path.Combine(@"D:\DataDownloadCenter", path2), ExtractOptions.Overwrite);
        }
        catch { }
     }
}
```

This way `fs` is closed even if `path` doesn't contain `.rar`. You're only closing the `fs` if `rar` exists within the filename.

Also, does the library have its own stream handling? It could have a method that closes it.

Comment: the library didn't have a stream handling. for the `zf` : `ZipFile zf = null;`

Comment: i also have this problem. nether the close() or a using seems to want to dispose the object. better find another lib.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue with nunrar, nether close() or a using statement seem to fix this. 
unfortunately the Documentation is scarce, so im now using the [SharpCompress library](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress) it is a fork of the nunrar library [according to the devs of nunrar](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=nunrar).The documentation on SharpCompress is also scarce (but less) so here is my method im using:

```
private static bool unrar(string filename)
{
    bool error = false;
    string outputpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);

    try
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            var reader = ReaderFactory.Open(stream);
            while (reader.MoveToNextEntry())
            {
                if (!reader.Entry.IsDirectory)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.Entry.Key);
                    reader.WriteEntryToDirectory(outputpath, new ExtractionOptions() { ExtractFullPath = true, Overwrite = true });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed: " + e.Message);
        error = true;
    }

    if (!error)
    {
        File.Delete(filename);
    }
    return error;
}
```

Add the following libraries to the top

```
using SharpCompress.Common;
using SharpCompress.Readers;
```

Install using nuget.This method works for SharpCompress v0.22.0(latest at the time of writing)